# no such file to load -- rush (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, passenger

Ruby version : 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux] Rails version : 2.3.5 Application Server : Passenger-4.0.41 OS: Cloud Linux 64 bit

I am trying to run, a old RoR application, which is the requirement. All requirements are installed. But, I get the following, when I try access via browser, I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- rush (MissingSourceFile)
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'gem_original_require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in 'require'
  /home/chennaim/public_html/demo/proj_rails_app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/worker.rb:1
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'gem_original_require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in 'require'
  /home/chennaim/public_html/demo/proj_rails_app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed_job.rb:6
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'gem_original_require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in 'require'
  /home/chennaim/public_html/demo/proj_rails_app/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/init.rb:1:in 'evaluate_init_rb'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in 'evaluate_init_rb'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in 'silence_warnings'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in 'evaluate_init_rb'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in 'load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in 'load_plugins'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in 'each'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in 'load_plugins'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in 'load_plugins'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in 'process'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'send'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'run'
  /home/chennaim/public_html/demo/proj_rails_app/config/environment.rb:6
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'gem_original_require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:96:in 'preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@global/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/classic-rails-preloader.rb:184
```

Please guide me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about to run

`gem install rush`

Comment: I did that, before itself. I even reloaded "rvm", and "web server". But, still the same.